# Is the series of sine function of integer squared, divided by the integer, summable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(k^2\right)}{k}$ converge? I am guessing it does, though the standard convergence tests/criteria do not seem to help.

Comment: It seems so -- thanks!